# Splitting request from query string

Tags: vb.net

I was wondering how in VB.net would you split part of a querystring to grab a post request?

So if I have a URL that outputs as follows, how would I grab just the ID part?

```
www.urlhere.com/name=whatever?id=someid
```

I need to grab the specific section of the ?id= and I assumed that the following would work in VB.net.

```
someString = Request.QueryString("?id")
```

This doesn't however grab the correct portion of the querystring. Can anyone point me in the direction of where I'm going wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: I have and it fails to pick up the actual ID.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want this: "?id=34"
Try this:

```
    Dim url As String = "www.urlhere.com/name=whatever?id=someid"

    Dim selectId As String = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf("?id="), url.Length - url.LastIndexOf("?id="))
```

In case you want only this: "?id="

```
   Dim url As String = "www.urlhere.com/name=whatever?id=someid"

   Dim selectId As String = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf("?id="), 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have current context available to you (so, if you are actually doing this in a web app where you need to read the request query string) you can do this.

```
Dim id As String = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("id")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should grab whatever is behine the "=" in id

```
Dim id as string
id = Request.QueryString("id")
```

Answer (score 0):

A thorough way to go through it so you can see at which stage it is going wrong:

```
Imports System.Web ' remember to add a reference to System.Web '

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim s = "http://www.urlhere.com/name=whatever?id=someid"
        Dim u = New Uri(s)
        Dim q = u.Query
        Dim parts = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(q)
        Console.WriteLine(parts("id"))
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs: someid